# Boost property tree to string

Tags: c++, boost

Need to transfer system configuration that is stored in ini file over internet. I'm using boost to deal with configuration ini file. How to save whole property tree to string?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just write to a `std::stringstream`:

```
std::ostringstream oss;
boost::property_tree::ini_parser::write_ini(oss, my_ptree);

std::string inifile_text = oss.str();
```

Replace with `wstring`/`wostringstream` as appropriate